# testing .success and .error of service in controller jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-services, angular-controller

I have a call to service's function in a controller. Below is the code

**Service**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('MyApp')
    .service('MyService', ['$http', function ($http) {                                                  
        return {
            getMyData: function (extension) {                                        
                return $http.get('www.something.com');
            }                
        };
    }])
})();
```

**Controller**

```
var getMyData = function () {
            MyService.getMyData(extension).success(function (results) {
                //Some functionality here
            })
                .error(function (err, status) {
                //Some functionality here
            });
        }
$scope.Call=function(){
    getMyData();
}
$scope.Call();
```

Now please tell me how to mock the service call (may be with providers). How to test the above functions with complete code coverage.

**My spec file:**

```
$provide.service("MyService", function () {
            this.getMyData= function () {
                var result = {
                    success: function (callback) {
                        return callback({ ServerFileName: "myserverfilename"});
                    },
                    error: function (callback) {
                        return callback({ ServerFileName: "myserverfilename" });
                    }
                };
                return result;
}           

//......
my controller initiation and other code
```

This code is not covering error block and giving the error

```
Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
```

Please help me how to write/mock the getMyData function of my service in my spec file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since `.success` and `.error` are old and have been replaced with `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)`, you should consider replacing your chained `.success` and `.error` calls with a single call to the `.then` method with two callbacks as arguments to it: first being a success callback and second being an error callback.

If that's what you're willing to do, here's your working example:

You **Module, Service and Controller**

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);

angular.module('MyApp')
.service('MyService', ['$http', function ($http) {                                                  
    return {
        getMyData: function (extension) {                                        
            return $http.get('www.something.com');
        }                
    };
}]);

angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var extension = { foo: 'bar' };
    var getMyData = function () {
        MyService.getMyData(extension).then(function (results) {
            //Some functionality here
        }, function (err, status) {
            //Some functionality here
        });
    }
    $scope.Call=function(){
        getMyData();
    }
    $scope.Call();
}]);
```

And your **Test**

```
describe('Controller: MyAppController', function(){
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
    var flag, extension, $q;
    extension = { foo: "bar" };
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _MyService_, _$q_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MyService = _MyService_;
        $q = _$q_;
        spyOn(MyService, 'getMyData').and.callFake(function(){
            return flag ? $q.when(): $q.reject();
        });
        MyAppController = $controller('MyAppController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            MyService: MyService
        });
    }));

    describe('function: Call', function() {
        //Text for Success Callback
        it('should implicitly call MyService.getMyData with an extension object', function() {
            flag = true;
            $scope.Call();
            expect(MyService.getMyData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(extension);
        });
        //Text for Error Callback
        it('should implicitly call MyService.getMyData with an extension object', function() {
            flag = false;
            $scope.Call();
            expect(MyService.getMyData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(extension);
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
I've tried making something like this to work but with no luck. Since `.error()`'s call is chained to `.success()` call, and that is something that will get called only after `.success()` has been called, it will never get to `.error()`'s call and we'll not be able to mock `.error()`. So if we try doing that, we'll always get an error like:

> Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

So either you can use the comment `/*istanbul ignore next*/` to skip this part in the coverage, or switch to `.then()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Do you mean that there is no way to test success and error blocks without changing them to then? I know how to write using then. But now we do not have access to change our source code. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spyon which would create some sort of mock for your service. You need to do this in your test file. Please check the below code:

```
spyOn(MyService, "getMyData").and.callFake(() => {
            return {
                error: (callback) => {
                    return callback({});
                }
            };
        });
```

Hope i answered your question

Comment: where should I write this code inside a provider or spec(it)?

Comment: you have to write this in beforeeach. Something like this:

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((MyService) => {

var _myService = MyService;

spyOn(_myService , "getMyData").and.callFake(() => {
            return {
                error: (callback) => {
                    return callback({});
                }
            };
        });
}

Comment: When I do this in beforeEach it is showing the error "MyService.getMyData(...).success is not a function"

Comment: Can you please give me a working example. I need it badly! I am unable to test this.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**. I had also encountered similar issue. Look like we have to design our own code and **Jasmine** allows us to **design, customize the callback method**. **In chaining**, return **this** object is mandate for Javascript method chaining. Using **my solution** you **dont** need to use **then** function

```
$provide.service("MyService", function () {
            this.getMyData= function () {
                var result = {
                    success: function (callback) {
                        callback({ ServerFileName: "myserverfilename"});
                        //returning main object for error callback invoke to occur
                        return this;

                    },
                    error: function (callback) {
                        callback({ ServerFileName: "myserverfilename" });
                        //returning this object will initialize error callback with object since you are chaining
                        return this;
                    }
                };
                return result;
}
```