# Test an Angular service by expecting a function call: Jasmine createSpy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have a controller that calls a service function, by passing in 2 functions as parameters (to be called dependent on the outcome of the service function), like so:

Controller code:

```
onSuccess(data){ ... }
onError(data){ ... }

service.post(url, query, onSuccess, onError);
```

Service code:

```
var service = function($log, $http, $location, $interval) {
...
    var post = function(url, query, onSuccess, onError){
        $http.post(url, query)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                onSuccess(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                onError(data);
            });
    };
...
});
```

What I'm trying to do is test that the query passed into the post function is correct and so the onSuccess function located within the controller code is called. I've tried to test this like so:

Test code:

```
describe("post", inject(function (service) {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        var url = "http://..."
        var query = {
            ...
        }
        var mockSuccess = jasmine.createSpy('Success function');
        var mockError = jasmine.createSpy('Error function');

        service.post(url, query, mockSuccess, mockError);
    }

    it('Should call success function following call to http.post', function () {

        expect(mockSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });

))};
```

Although I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.$modules')
```

So I'm not sure how to properly test whether my query is successful in returning data through the http request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your code right? I did not see a declaration for `mockSuccess`.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I had to change a few function names to put it on here, so missed a few things.

Comment: see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631026/testing-success-and-error-of-service-in-controller-jasmine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [testing .success and .error of service in controller jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631026/testing-success-and-error-of-service-in-controller-jasmine)